# Modify TabbedPage Bar with handler in .NET Maui (Android)

Tags: maui

I'm trying to add margin to tabbedPage Bar. I created and added a custom mapper entry ("MyCustomMargin") that will create a new layout and set the margin. But is not working. I don't know what im doing wrong?

This is my tabbedPage with default Bar Ui:
https://ibb.co/8DVtvfS

This is how i want the Bar Ui to be: https://ibb.co/YNVKvrt

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.TabbedViewHandler.Mapper.Add("MyCustomMargin", (handler, view) =>
        {
                
            View tabbedPageView = handler.PlatformView as View;

            MarginLayoutParams layout = new(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            layout.SetMargins(500, 500, 500, 100);

            tabbedPageView.LayoutParameters = layout;

            tabbedPageView.RequestLayout();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may cascade customizations in mappers with AppendToMapping and PrependToMapping or modify the whole mapping altogether with ModifyMapping. This means that instead of this line:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.TabbedViewHandler.Mapper.Add("MyCustomMargin", (handler, 
view) =>
```

You may change it to:

```
 Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.TabbedViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomMargin", (handler, view) =>
```

For more information about it, you can refer to the link："https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-specific-control-instance".I hope it can help you.